# Proof verification for convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, weak-convergence

I want to prove the following theorem, and I'm not sure if the proof I currently have works:

Let $Y_{n,k}$ and $Z_n$ be random variablesfor $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

(1) $Y_{n,k} \xrightarrow{d} Y_k$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for each $k$

(2) $Y_{k} \xrightarrow{d} Y$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$

(3) For every $\epsilon > 0$, $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|Z_n - Y_{n,k}| > \epsilon) = 0$

Then $Z_n \xrightarrow{d} Y$

---

**My proof:**

It suffices to show that $|E(f(Z_n) - f(Y))| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for each bounded, Lipschitz continuous function $f$.  Let $M >$ maximum of Lipschitz constant and the bound for $f$.

By (3) there exists $K_1$ such that $k \ge K_1$ implies $\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sup_{m \ge n} P(|Z_m - Y_{m, k}| > \epsilon/6M) < \epsilon/12M$

By (2) there exists $K_2$ such that $k \ge K_2$ implies $|E(f(Y_k) - f(Y))| < \epsilon/3$

Put $K = \max\{K_1, K_2\}$.  By (1) there exists an $N_1$ corresponding to the fixed $K$ for which $|E(f(Y_{n,K}) - f(Y_K))|$ for each $n \ge N_1$.

Since $K \ge K_1$, we have there exists an $N_2$ such that for each $n \ge N_2$ $P(|Z_n - Y_{n, K}| > \epsilon/6M) < \epsilon/12M$

Now for $n \ge N \equiv \max\{N_1, N_2\}$, we have $$|E(f(Z_n) - f(Y))| \leq E(|f(Z_n) - f(Y_{n,K})|) + |E(f(Y_{n,K}) - f(Y_K))| + |E(f(Y_K)-f(Y))| \\ < \frac{2 \epsilon}{3} + E(|f(Z_n) - f(Y_{n,K})| \mathbf{1}(|Z_n - Y_{n,K}| > \epsilon/6M)) + E(|f(Z_n) - f(Y_{n,K})| \mathbf{1}(|Z_n - Y_{n,K}| 
 \leq \epsilon/6M)) \\ \leq \frac{2 \epsilon}{3} + 2M E(\mathbf{1}(|Z_n - Y_{n,K}| > \epsilon/6M)) + E(M|Z_n - Y_{n,K}| \mathbf{1}(|Z_n - Y_{n,K}| 
 \leq \epsilon/6M)) \\ < \frac{2 \epsilon}{3} + 2M \epsilon/ 12M + M\epsilon / 6M = \epsilon$$

My main question is this: the above is justified because we picked $K$ solely based on $\epsilon$ and thus $N$ solely based on $K$ and $\epsilon$, so that $N$ is only determined by $\epsilon$, and the definition of convergence in distribution is thus satisfied, right?